# IP address discovering for FPGA embedded system using UDP

Tags: networking, udp, embedded, ethernet

I am developing an Ethernet connected embedded system. The embedded system's network stack is limited, I do not want to use TCP/IP.

The IP address of the embedded system can be configured by the user and there is scope for that IP address to be forgotten by the user. I'm looking for a simple method for discovering that IP address. The embedded system does not have a display.

I can guarantee that the embedded system and PC performing the discovery are on the same local network. There may be a ethernet switch between the two devices, but no router. However, it is possible that the embedded system will have been configured with an IP address from a completely different subnet.

My plan is to send a UDP broadcast to the network. The embedded system receives this and will respond with its serial number and currently configured IP address. I have successfully got the UDP broadcast to the embedded system, but I am struggling with the source IP address for the response sent by the embedded system.

Even if the destination IP address, destination MAC address and source MAC address are correct (non-broadcast), if the source IP address is from a different subnet, the UDP packet isn't received by the PC (It isn't shown in Wireshark on Windows 10). An illustration of what I'm trying to do is below:

[image]

1. Is it possible to use something else for the source address (possibly the network address)?
2. I'm wondering if there are any other approaches to this problem?

I'm looking for a solution that does not require any special user permissions on the PC and ideally can be programmed in C#.

Comment: Are there any reasons I am currently missing  why using a very simple, link layer, standard discovery protocol such as [LLDP](https://standards.ieee.org/standard/802_1AB-2016.html)  would not fulfil your requirements ? I think the IP management address for the embedded system could be on of the TLV it could send back to the PC - in the scenario, this PC would use LLDP as well . If this is the case, I would suggest not to waste any more time re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: If the device is configured for a different network, you´ll never get any reply over IP to your machine (since it will be directed to the device´s configured default gateway which does not exists. ARP resolution will already fail). If you really want to handle that use case, the embedded system needs to have some autoconfig capability (and a reset possibility!).

Comment: @Frant, LLDP looks like an interesting option. Ideally I need to be able to perform my discovery operation without special permissions using .NET and c#. From what I can see because this operates on the Link Layer, this may not be possible.

Comment: @C.Gonzalez please could you clarify your statement about 'directed to the device's configured gateway'. My embedded system is VERY low level, it has no concept of a gateway. I'm 'hand' crafting the UDP packet and I'm fairly sure it is physically being transmitted by the embedded system's PHY. I'm assuming the response packet is making it to the PC (unless the network switch is filtering it). The PC will not do an ARP resolution as it is broadcasting. The embedded system knows the correct destination MAC & IP addresses from the discovery packet.

Comment: Is the Windows Firewall active on the PC? By default it will block UDP from any source that was not targeted by a recently-sent unicast datagram.

Comment: This sounds like a huge PITA. How do you want to interface with a switch without implementing TCP/IP? Also you note FPGA in your title but nothing specific to that is in your question.

Comment: @Andy: Yes, permissions may be an issue on the PC. Will your system be deployed on a network you will have some degree of control on, or not at all ? Will you have some control on the PC configuration, at least at install time, or not at all ? This is what I see should guide your technical response.

Comment: @Andy: What is the maximum number of your embedded devices  you expect to be residing on the same Ethernet network, along with the PC ?

Comment: @Frant: As this is a recovery process, we can define a procedure that insists the PC is directly attached to the embedded system (this is quite reasonable for the system I'm developing). Therefore, there ideally will only be one system attached during recovery. The user will be expected to install software for use with the embedded system, Administrator privileges are not our of the question, but I wanted to avoid complicated installation processes of third party libraries/tools.

Comment: @TarickWelling: I don't want/need to communicate with the actual network switch. I was just highlighting that it might be in the network between the embedded system and the PC. You're right about the FPGA bit. I was just trying to get across the 'limitations' of the embedded system. Also, I see what I'm trying to achieve as a common problem, especially for FPGA type projects. I thought this might help people in the future looking for a similar solution.

Comment: @Andy: In this case, you could just have a requirement consisting in your PC having a 802.1Q interface for management purpose only, using say VLAN ID 1,  a management network being 192.168.1.0/24, the PC IP on this network would always be, say, 192.168.1.1, and the embedded system would always answer with, say 192.168.1.2 as its source IP. You could use a unicast UDP discovery packet, and forging a unicast UDP response packet on a VLAN is obvious. Using a VLAN for discovery would facilitate filtering non-discovery packets on the embedded device side as well.